How do I create an object from a ResultSet?
I'm trying to write a method the recieves an id an returns an object from a database, but it keeps returning null instead.
public Seller findById(int id) throws SQLException {

        Seller seller = null;
        String query = "SELECT seller.*, department.name as DepName FROM seller INNER JOIN department ON seller.department_id = department.departmentID WHERE seller.id = ?"; 
        Connection connection = DataBaseConnection.connect();
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        pstmt.setInt(1, id);
        result = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(result.next()) {
            Department dep = createDepartment(result);
            seller = createSeller(result, dep);
        }

        DataBaseConnection.closeStatement(pstmt);
        DataBaseConnection.closeResultSet(result);

        return seller;
}

private Seller createSeller(ResultSet result, Department dep) throws SQLException {
    int idSeller = result.getInt("id");
    String name = result.getString("name");
    String email = result.getString("email");
    Date birthDate = result.getDate("birthDate");
    double salary = result.getDouble("salary");
    return new Seller(idSeller, name, email, birthDate, salary, dep);
}

private Department createDepartment(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    int depId = rs.getInt("departmentId");
    String depName = rs.getString("name");
    return new Department(depId, depName);
}

createDepartment(result) and createSeller(result, dep) methods should instantiate objects by passing the data retrieved from the database to the constructors of Seller and Department classes. I've got stuck on this for hours, can someone help ?

Could you add more detail about which line returns null object?Also you need to make sure that your sql will return at least one records

check what your column names are in the resultset e.g. should rs.getInt("departmentId"); not be department_id  - I am not sure what they will be when using the join, assuming the join returns something.

As the comments above suggest you provided very little information try to add a db table structure and logs etc. At this point, one can only guess what is happening in your application.

I would much sooner expect an exception about the column departmentId not being found (as your result set only has department_id) than a null (unless there is no row at all). Please provide a [mre].

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you saying that findById() is returning null? Or that createSeller() is returning null? Or both?We love to help, but please be very precise about the problem that we should help you with.

Case sensitive
You have:
INNER JOIN department ON seller.department_id = department.departmentID

and
int depId = rs.getInt("departmentId");

Notice the diference in your capitalization of ID in departmentId.
Spelling
Also you have:
department.name as DepName

and
String depName = rs.getString("name");

I beleive you will want to be doing rs.getString("DepName").

I'm going to go ahead and guess you have some naming inconsistencies. One of the hardest parts about web dev will be keeping your variable names consistent across your backend, frontend, and database. Small deviations will cause a headache. Make sure to triple check them.
Also, try running your query within a database administration tool. It helps to make sure you're actually returning rows within your result set first. I recommend DBeaver, but many exist.

The ResultSet.getXXX(String) methods are explicitly documented to retrieve columns case-insensitively (from Resultset documentation: "Column names used as input to getter methods are case insensitive. When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns have the same name, the value of the first matching column will be returned."), so the first part of your answer does not apply. The problem is that they don't select department.departmentID, but only seller.department_id, so rs.getInt("departmentId") will throw an exception.
